# Setting element content with lxml removes trailing whitespaces

Tags: python, xml, svg, lxml, inkscape

I am currently trying to create an svg image using the [lxml library](http://lxml.de/). However, I create some tspace elements to structure and format the text within text elements, but if I try to set the content of such a tspace element to something like "Hello World ", the trailing whitespace is removed and I get `<tspace>Hello World</tspace>` as result. But I would like to keep this whitespace.

At this point it is important to mention, that I just have access to the Tree object, but I do not initialize the parser. So if I have to change some parser flags, I could not access the parser directly. Following a small example of my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys, os

class HelloPlugin(inkex.Effect):
    def __init__(self):
        # Call the base class constructor.
        inkex.Effect.__init__(self)

    def effect(self):
        # Fetch the svg root element (lxml etree element) ...
        svg = self.document.getroot()

        # ... as well as the image width and height.
        width  = inkex.unittouu(svg.get('width'))
        height = inkex.unittouu(svg.get('height'))
        fontSize = 12

        # Create a new layer.
        layer = inkex.etree.SubElement(svg, 'g')
        layer.set(inkex.addNS('label', 'inkscape'), 'Headline Layer')
        layer.set(inkex.addNS('groupmode', 'inkscape'), 'layer')

        # Create the text element, ...
        text = inkex.etree.SubElement(layer, inkex.addNS('text','svg'))
        text.set('x', str(width / 2 + fontSize))
        text.set('y', str(height / 2 + fontSize / 2))

        # ... define text style and position ...
        style = {
            'font-size': str(fontSize)
        }

        # ... and set the text style.
        text.set('style', formatStyle(style))

        # Finally create the tspan element.
        tspan = inkex.etree.SubElement(text, inkex.addNS('tspan','svg'))
        tspan.text = "Hello Plugin "

def main(argv):
    cubify = Cubify()
    cubify.affect()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

So my question is, how I have to change the above example to get `<tspace>Hello Plugin </tspace>` instead of `<tspace>Hello plugin</tspace>` in the resulting svg file.

Comment: You meant 'tspan' and not 'tspace'? The space at the end of the text should be there. How about trying `self.document.write(sys.stdout)` at the end of the method to see what you get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for the [`tail` property of XML elements](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html#elements-contain-text) in the `lxml.tree` library. Here's what the docs say about it:

> However, if XML is used for tagged text documents such as (X)HTML, text can also appear between different elements, right in the middle of the tree:
>
> `<html><body>Hello<br/>World</body></html>`
>
> Here, the `<br/>` tag is surrounded by text. This is often referred to as document-style or mixed-content XML. Elements support this through their `tail` property. It contains the text that directly follows the element, up to the next element in the XML tree:

In your case, the contents of `tail` is the whitespace. Here's an example:

```
import lxml.etree as ET
x = ET.fromstring("<foo> <bar>blah</bar>    </foo>")
bar = x.find("bar")
print( repr(bar.tail) )
```

Prints:

```
'    '
```

Comment: Yeah, I tried this. In my example above this would be `tspan.tail = ' '`, but this does not work. Is there anything else, I have to do?

Comment: Did you see the note in the docs about using `.to_string(with_tail=True)` to ensure that the tail is retained in string output? Your code doesn't show how/where you are serializing the output, so I can only speculate.

Comment: Mhhh, that's the problem, I do not serialize the code. This is part of an Inkscape plugin and I just modify the svg document tree, creation, parsing and serializing is handled by the plugin system. Is there a possibility to set this globally?

Comment: At what point do you actually care about the whitespace in `tail`? Does Inkscape's truncation of `tail` actually affect the output?

Comment: I set the whitespace directly after setting the text. The output is affected, so if I open the generated svg file with a text editor, the spaces are missing.

Comment: I'm thinking you'll have better luck on the `inkex.py` mailing list or forums, or diving through the extension code as a last resort. What you're outputting is totally reasonable, but it's dependent on how someone else decides to serialize it.

Comment: @Bornageek I'm not sure if the inkex mailing list was able to solve this problem or not, but it's worth noting that this question, as it is presented, doesn't actually deal with `tail`s. The OP's tspan/tspace element is presented as being a leaf node (ie. it has no children; text is its only quasi-"child"). The tricky handling of tails would only come into play if, somewhere in some code the OP isn't showing us, an "additional" subelement was added to the tspan/tspace element that already contained the "Hello Plugin " text.

Comment: As @DanLenski said, the culprit here is likely whoever is serializing the tree to an SVG file. A good way to test to make sure it's not something else would be to insert some debug code in the middle of there: serialize the tspan element, or even the entire element tree to someplace accessible (stdout, maybe? or a writable file that opened up and examined).Then, at least one can verify that the lxml installation is behaving as expected. As I learned, sometimes it doesn't: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36004047/why-does-lxml-html-sometimes-swallow-remove-whitespace-instead-of-preserving-it